# mongodump failed connecting to monogdb after version downgrade

Tags: mongodb, cloud-foundry, mongodump, swisscomdev

Since I use mongodb-clients 2.6.10 the mongodump doesn't work anymore. With the previous version 3.4.7 everything worked fine. It is a dedicated mongodb database as a service in the CF AppCloud where nothing has been changed. Unfortunately, it is not possible to use version 3.4.7 again. 
Does anyone have an idea why it doesn't work anymore?

```
vcap@host:~$ mongodump -u XXX -p XXX -d XXX --authenticationDatabase XXX -h kubernetes-service-node.service.consul:XXX,kubernetes-service-node.service.consul:XXX,kubernetes-service-node.service.consul:XXX
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/yz1kp68p/

Comment: have you tried restarting mongoDB

Comment: I can't restart the service, but the problem also exist with several other mongodb's

Comment: try after removing the auth for `mongo.conf` file

Comment: I can't find a mongo.conf file

Comment: find in etc/var/lib

Comment: I still have no mongo.conf file...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I successfully installed mongo-tools from the Ubuntu artful repository to have a mongodump version that supports SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication mechanism. The dumper app now works without problems.
Installing mongodb-clients out of the artful repository did not work in my case, but mongo-tools did it.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the error, it's probably got nothing to do with the mongodump version. Can you generally connect to the database (i.e. with the mongo shell instead of mongodump)? My guess is that the app either isn't bound (cf bind-service) to the database or hasn't been restaged (cf restage) after being bound - both is necessary to enable firewall access from the app to the database. Also, why can't you use a newer mongodump version anymore? Sounds more like that's what needs to be addressed in the first place.

Comment: Yes I can connect to the db over a service connector and Studio 3T. The db service is now correctly bound to the app (I found also a problem there before). The db is already bound to the app by pushing, so no restage is necessary anymore. Now I have a new error message:

Comment: connected to: kubernetes-service-node.service.consul:51833
assertion: 18 { ok: 0.0, errmsg: "auth failed", code: 18, codeName: "AuthenticationFailed" }

Comment: I have checked the credentials several times and I can guarantee that they are correct...

Comment: @seinol hm, checking the documentation, mongodump only started to support the SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication mechanism with 3.0, so an older version won't work. As I said before, the issue you need to address is why you can't using a newer version, as 2.6 is terribly old.

Comment: Ahh yes, sorry I forgot to answer you this. The container where I use mongodump is an Ubuntu trusty (14.04), so out of the package repo is only mongodb-clients 2.6 available. 
It's extremly hard to install an newer version on trusty, because the package has very much deps and I have to install them over a buildpack (https://github.com/cloudfoundry/apt-buildpack).

Comment: I made last year a hotfix... I managed to install a running mongodb-clients package with the repos from zesty, but unfortunately zesty is out of life... I had no success with other hacks (i.e. other versions) until today

Comment: @seinol If that's somehow possible with the apt-buildpack, use the repo and packages provided by MongoDB: https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.4/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/
...or upgrade to xenial or such. Becauce there's no way you can get this working with the 2.6 clients, I'm afraid.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can isntall packages only via the apt-buildpack, because I don't have enough permissions in the linux container. I tried thousands of variants with the buildpack, but without success.
An update to Xenial is also not possible. I'll have to find a completely different solution. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @seinol Why do you want to mongodump from within the app container in the first place? In most cases using an ssh tunnel (cf ssh -L) and using mongodump locally would make more sense.

Comment: The App which I use the mongodump inside is an automated sql dumper app. Actually she is dumping all mysql db's in the cloud and storing the dumps to an s3 storage. So it would be nice when the same app also can dump the nosql db's automatically.